# Grails session-scoped service - not working

Tags: session, grails

I added `static scope = "session"` in one of my Grails services (Grails 2.2.2), but for some reason it is behaving like a singleton.

Can you not inject session services into singleton (default) services?

In other words, is there any reason why this shouldn't work?

```
class DefaultService {
  def sessionService
}

class SessionService {
  static scope = 'session'

  def instanceVar = ...
}
```

How would I troubleshoot why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope [this](http://ldaley.com/post/436635056/scoped-services-proxies-in-grails) help you.

In short, you can not use session scoped services in singletons, like usual services or taglibs. Use service proxy by manually, or [Scoped Proxy Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/scoped-proxy).

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.  If you inject a session service into a singleton, Grails / Spring will happily let you, but not give you what you want.  It will inherit the longer scope since scoping is only applied when the singleton is created.  

This surprised me because a similar mistake with JSF managed beans would have been an error, and in CDI, it would have made proxies automatically.