# Grails Session Scoped bean data state not updated correctly

Tags: session, grails

I have a Grails web application in which I need to keep some data per user session. I don't want to use HTTP Session, and rather create a session scoped bean. Given below is my Session Scoped bean definition -

```
class SessionContainer implements Serializable {

    static scope = 'session' (if I am using resources.groovy)

    Boolean abc
    Boolean def
    Boolean xyz
    SomeOtherChildBean someBean
}
```

**This is how my Controller looks like :**

```
class MyController {

    def myService

    def showMyProblem() {
      myService.updateSession()
      myService.printSessionData()
    }
}
```

**This is how my Service class look like :**

```
class MyService {

    SessionContainer sessionContainer

    def updateSession() {
      sessionContainer.abc = true
      sessionContainer.def = true
      sessionContainer.xyz = true
    }

    def printSessionData() {
        def abc = sessionContainer.abc
        def def = sessionContainer.def
        def xyz = sessionContainer.xyz
        println abc // This is always false (which is incorrect)
        println def // This is true (which is correct)
        println xyz // This is true (which is correct)
    }
}
```

**I injected the session bean using 2 ways - 
In resources.groovy -**

```
sessionContainerBean(SessionContainer) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'session'
}
sessionContainer(org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
    targetBeanName = 'sessionContainerBean'
    proxyTargetClass = true
}
```

OR in resources.xml

```
<bean id="sessionContainer" name="sessionContainer" class="com.dataobjects.SessionContainer" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I tried 2 different ways to inject session scoped bean to solve my problem, although eaither of abobe mentioned way resulted in same Session Scoped bean.

As you can see from my code, I am printing the boolean variables from my Session scoped bean, and **abc** value is always false (which is incorrect). When printing other boolean variables, it render correct values.

I am freaked out on how come session bean has correct state for few variables, but not updating the state for certain variables.

I have even tried using Session Scoped service by using (static scope = 'true') but got below error - and I ended up creating a proxy scoped service as described here [Grails session-scoped service - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724567/grails-session-scoped-service-not-working) , but same behavior as Session Scoped bean.

```
Error creating bean with name 'myService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread
```

Comment: The service class is singleton by default. `sessionContainer` in myService might be from other request since a state is maintained for that variable in service class.

Comment: That's why 'sessionContainer' is injected as Session Scoped variables. Generally same is followed in Spring based apps where a session scoped variable is injected in Spring based singleton Service class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyService` is a real Grails service defined under `grails-app/services/` then you don't need to define the bean in `resources.groovy` or in `resources.xml`.  You can express the scope as a static property:

```
// grails-app/services/demo/MyService.groovy
package demo

class MyService {
    static scope = 'session'

    // ...
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: You may have to manage scope of some of the related beans, depending on some other factors in your app.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks a lot for your response.  I don't want MyService to be session based, rather have a Bean (SessionContainer) injected in MyService class.  I am against the idea of declaring the service class to be Session scoped, as services should be state-less and Singleton.

Comment: You will need to resolve issues referencing a session scoped bean from a singleton bean.

Comment: You are already submitting that you want to have a session scoped bean holding on to state.  If you are going to do that anyway, just use a session scoped service. You are introducing complexity for reasons that are not apparent to me from the description.

Comment: Saying "services should be state-less and Singleton" and then saying "I have a Grails web application in which I need to keep some data per user session" seems to suggest that you are being dogmatic about wanting stateless services in a case where it doesn't really make sense to be.  The fact that it is a "service" isn't really a factor here.  You want a session scoped bean to hold on to state.  If you want that and think that is a good idea, why is it problematic for that bean to be a service?

Comment: Jeff, I see where you going. Let me try making "SessionContainer" to be a Session scoped service and see if that solve my problem. I still don't want "MyService" to be Session scoped, reason for that is, it reference many other singleton services to do some more operations.

Comment: That makes sense to me.

Comment: I tried creating the service with name MyService (just for testing) with session scope, I got following error. I am using grails 2.3.6                            -  Error creating bean with name 'myService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?

Comment: I think I might end up again using resource.groovy  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724567/grails-session-scoped-service-not-working